# How to pass Datatable as Ref_Cursor into Oracle Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, odp.net, ref-cursor

How to pass Data table as Ref_Cursor into Oracle Procedure ? I am using ODP.NET and Oracle 10g client in my development box.